# Hide header tags in WKHTMLPDF TOC

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, tableofcontents

I'm trying to generate a PDF Catalog including a table of contens with wkhtmltopdf.

To achieve this I create a toc dump, and read it's content through PHP. So long - no problem...

Now I have some headers, that have to be display inside the TOC, but not in the rendered PDF. So I set the mentioned headers to "display: none". If I do so, they don't appear in the TOC.

I need a possibility to render some headers into the TOC without displaying them in the PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using --xsl-style-sheet option and using a customized XSL. You can add any content to it.